# Is Java thread a daemon 'if and only if' the creating thread is a daemon?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, daemon

According to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread):

> When code running in some thread creates a new `Thread` object, the new thread has its priority initially set equal to the priority of the creating thread, and **is a daemon thread *if and only if* the creating thread is a daemon.**

Is it correct to use the expression ***'if and only if'*** here?

I thought we can make a daemon thread by using `setDaemon(true)`, even if the main thread is a non-daemon thread.

I want to know if I misunderstood the concept.

---

here is the code I tried:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean isDaemon;
        isDaemon = Thread.currentThread().isDaemon();
        System.out.println("Is main thread daemon?:" + isDaemon);
        new WorkerThread(true).start();
    }
}

class WorkerThread extends Thread {
    public WorkerThread(boolean tf) {
        setDaemon(tf);
    }

    public void run() {
        boolean isDaemon;
        isDaemon = Thread.currentThread().isDaemon();
        System.out.println("Is worker thread daemon?:" + isDaemon);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the default behaviour of the daemon thread. If you create a thread from a daemon thread then it will be daemon by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct but the docs are correct as well.

When you create a new Thread inherits its daemon state from its creating Thread, at this point the new thread is daemon **if and only if** the creating Thread is daemon as well.

Afterwards you can call `setDaemon(...)` and change the daemon state but that does not invalidate the original claim. The original claim is basically only talking about the Thread creation, not about its future lifecycle / configuration.

The code in the question just moves the changing of the daemon flag to somewhere else. When you call `setDaemon(tf);` the thread is already configured to be non-daemon and you simply change that config. Note that the android specification only talks about the `Thread`, technically the documentation is completely irrelevant in your case since you deal with a `WorkerThread`. Practically of course most of the documentation still holds true, but precisely the statement about the thread inheriting the daemon state is no longer true since you explicitly changed that behaviour.

Comment: What if we use `setDaemon(true)` in the constructor of the worker thread? Doesn't it mean the worker thread is a daemon from the beginning?

Comment: @starriet you cannot set the deamon flag as a constructor parameter. You can only ever change the daemon flag after the Thread instance was created / initialized. Either the thread creating the thread is daemon or not. Then the child inherits that. Afterwards you can freely change the parent and child, but that does not invalidate that originally it inherited the flag.

Comment: hmm... sorry I didn't understand. I tried using `setDaemon` in the constructor of a worker thread, and it works well. I also tried passing boolean value to the constructor parameter and use that boolean into like `setDaemon(boolean_value)`, and it also works. What am I understand wrongly?

Comment: @starriet did you inherit the Thread class and provided your own custom Thread constructor for that? Maybe add that code to your question so I can explain why both statements hold true even in your scenario.

Comment: yes, I inherited the `Thread` class and provided a custom constructor. I added the code in the question! thanks a lot.

Comment: @starriet edited my answer. Basically: you change the default thread behaviour and by doing that invalidated the documentation. You did not contradict it any way, you simply created something new the documentation does no longer apply to.

Comment: Re, "... Afterwards you can freely change the parent and child." `t.setDaemon(...)` will throw an exception and have no effect on thread `t` if the thread has already been started, and there is no way for a thread to become a "parent" if it has _not_ already been started.